# GDB If statement return values?

Tags: debugging, gdb

Is there a way I can read if statements being evaluated? I mean, like get the return value of realpath in  -

```
if(realpath(path.c_str(), realPath) == 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [step into and finish](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#Continuing-and-Stepping) `realpath` function. The returned value will be printed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

at the gdb prompt (if you got debug symbols enabled when you compiled)

```
print realpath(path.c_str(),realPath)
```

it will print the result, very nifty.

Comment: but be careful with this solution. The function gets evaluated again, so if it has any side effects, this will corrupt your debug session. Better solution would be to step into the function, execute till it returns and check the return value

Comment: true about the side effect, it's the same as if you run that line of code

Comment: **display** will also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a memory pointer laying around on your code, you could use GDB to allocate new memory space for it it, and use it to store the result of the expression you want to evaluate.

Check [this page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_42.html) for more info.

```
(gdb) set variable p = malloc(sizeof(int))

(gdb) print p
$2 = (int *) 0x40013f98    (address allocated by malloc)

(gdb) set variable *p = 255

(gdb) print *p
$3 = 255
```